# HTTP Response headers collection cannot be modified in .NET Core web app

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, http-headers

I have this controller:

```
[PushHeaderAttribute]
 public class ClockController : Controller
 {

 }
```

Where PushHeaderAttribute is defined as follows:

```
public class PushHeaderAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("content-encoding", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.WebName);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("connection", "keep-alive ");
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

The attribute is called, but when debugging, the `context.HttpContext.Response.Headers` list is empty, however, when monitoring the response, all the headers are there.

How can I properly manipulate headers in .NET Core Web App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base headers like`Server` can't be removed,because it haven't be added in your scenario,it would be added  in Kestrel/IIS 's intrenal Pipe

If you do want to remove "Server" response header,you could configure as below for Kestrel(.Net 6 +):

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(op => 
{
    op.AddServerHeader = false;
});
```

For IIS, you could refer this [article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Jul/07/Back-to-Basics-Custom-HTTP-Response-Header-Manipulation-in-ASPNET-Core)

For `Connection` header ,you could check comment in the source codes of [HttpProtocol.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/72ee5732f00289191a7f89ce8000854e52de808c/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.cs#L1101)

```
// "This means that an intermediary transforming an HTTP/1.x message to HTTP/2 will need to remove any header fields
        // nominated by the Connection header field, along with the Connection header field itself.
        // Such intermediaries SHOULD also remove other connection-specific header fields, such as Keep-Alive,
        // Proxy-Connection, Transfer-Encoding, and Upgrade, even if they are not nominated by the Connection header field."
        //
        // Http/3 has a similar requirement: https://quicwg.org/base-drafts/draft-ietf-quic-http.html#name-field-formatting-and-compre
```

Comment: Thanks. And what about "connection" header? it does not appear in the response.

Comment: Hi,@jstuardo,it would be removed from an HTTP/2+ response by design,you could check the comment in source codes:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/72ee5732f00289191a7f89ce8000854e52de808c/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.cs#L1101